# Is it correct that OS-level virtualization is having several OS inside one virtual machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've started studying AWS, and in the process of it, I bumped into this term called ECS/EKS. In the explanation, it stated that they are a type of docker container, which uses "operating system level virtualization".
I've done some research, and I would like to check if my recognition that
it is having several OS in one virtual machine
correct. Also, if it is correct, I would like to know some actual examples of how this works, and also the benefits of using this specific technology.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[containerization `!=`  virtualization](https://www.netapp.com/blog/containers-vs-vms/) for sure.

- OS virtualization is where a single kernel manages the system, creating virtual OS instances that are isolated from each other.
  example : smart OS Zones

  - A key difference from hardware virtualization technologies is that only one kernel is running
- Hardware virtualization is where a hypervisor manages multiple guest operating systems, each running its own kernel with virtualized devices.
  examples: Xen and KVM. Kinds includes:

  - Full virtualization—binary translations
  - Full virtualization—hardware-assisted
  - Paravirtualization
  - Hybrid Virtualization
- different implementations of hardware virtualization includes : VMware ESX, XEN( open source and used by AWS and Rackspace), KVM(used by Google Cloud)

source : [Systems Performance: Enterprise and the Cloud, 2nd Edition](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2020-07-15/systems-performance-2nd-edition.html)

As far as the benefits are concerned they varies from implementation to implementation.

[You might find this helpful as well](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/whats-a-linux-container#:%7E:text=choose%20Red%20Hat%3F-,Overview,testing%2C%20and%20finally%20to%20production.)

for brevity I tried to use least amount of references , this topic can be easily expanded in to books.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!!!
would OS virtualization only having one kernel mean that it can only have several of the same kind of OS(such as having 2 linux running on the same kernel)while Hardware virtualization can have several different OS running??

Comment: @lei not sure what are referring to here by `Linux` . It is the kernel itself , OSes are based on that.Hardware virtualization creates system virtual machine instances, which can run entire operating systems, `including their kernels`.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. To clarify my question, in an OS virtualization is correct that you cannot run two OSes on a different kernel(such as windows and mac)?

Comment: @lei  yes you can with the help of various software available for virtualization like `VmWare`, `VirtualBox` etc.